# Confirm that the exponential distribution is correctly being used with the survreg() function of the survival package?

Tags: r, survival, exponential-distribution

I've been examining fitting the Weibull and lognormal distributions with the `survreg()` function of the `survival` package. Fitting the Weibull distribution took some transformation for standard parameterization (per R `dweibull()`) as shown here: [How to generate multiple forecast simulation paths for survival analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/614198/how-to-generate-multiple-forecast-simulation-paths-for-survival-analysis)

I'm now moving on to the exponential distribution. [See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/616351/how-to-assign-reasonable-scale-parameters-to-randomly-generated-intercepts-for-t for an example of the exponential distribution.] Could someone please confirm if the exponential distribution is being correctly fit in the R code posted at the bottom and as illustrated in the following image? If not, how do I correctly fit exponential? I only use the `lung` dataset for ease of example even though it doesn't provide good fit: Weibull provides the best fit.

[image]

Code:

```
library(survival)

time <- seq(0, 1000, by = 1)

fit <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung, dist = "exponential")

survival <- 1 - pexp(time, rate = 1 / fit$coef)

plot(time, survival, type = "l", xlab = "Time",ylab = "Survival Probability",col = "red", lwd = 3)
lines(survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung), col = "blue")
legend("topright",legend = c("Fitted exponential","Kaplan-Meier" ),col = c("red", "blue"),lwd = c(3, 1),bty = "n")
```

Comment: The red curve is obviously wrong.  Consider starting with `predict.survreg`.

Comment: See EdM answer below which completely resolves the wacky red line issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I had determined that initially -- it's easy to guess that's the problem and to check it -- but as a general proposition you ought to look at what the `predict` method does when you're learning your way around any regression procedure in `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gotten trapped by [location-scale modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/615237/28500) again. The model you fit is:

$$\log(T)\sim  \beta_0 + W, $$

where $\beta_0$ is your `fit$coef`  (location) and $W$ represents a standard minimum extreme value distribution. The scale factor multiplying $W$ for a corresponding Weibull model is set exactly to 1 for an exponential model.

Thus $\beta_0$ represents a value in the *log* scale of time. For linear time, you need to exponentiate it to get the `rate` argument to supply to `pexp()`.

```
1/exp(fit$coef)
# (Intercept) 
# 0.002370928
```

Try that.